# Firesbase database batch upload

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, nosql, google-cloud-storage

Is it possible to upload data in batch in Firebase? Say I have a collection into which I want to store 100 documents with the same fields but different field values. I have the data ready in a CSV or other text format. Is there a way to upload this data in batches? One of the fields in the documents is of imageUrl type and is a reference (pathname) to an image in Cloud Storage. How can I download paths from Storage? Thank you for your help in advance. bests

Comment: [Batched writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes) allow you to write up to 500 documents in one atomic action. But aside from atomicity there are no benefits to using a batch over performing individual writes.

Comment: Firestore (console) does not have an import or export function so you cannot directly upload a text file. That being said, it would be "trivial" to craft a quick app to read the text file and then write that data to Firestore as documents in a collection. Your question asks about uploading but then asks about downloading paths from Storage, which is a separate question, and again - it would be "trivial" to craft an app to read the contents of storage and then write it out to a flat file (text). Or am I misunderstanding the question?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to upload data in batch in Firebase?

Indeed there is. You can execute multiple write operations as a single batch. Here are the docs:

> https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes

As you can see, you can add up to 500 operations to a single batch. If you need more than that, then you should consider performing multiple batch operations.

Why would you use a batch and not individual writes? It's because of always having consistent data. If you do 500 operations without a batch, and for some reason, the 350'th operation fails, then you'll end up having only 350 out of 500 completed operations. Using a batch will ensure you that all the operations are complete, or failed with an exception. There won't be partial data or rolled-back operations.

> One of the fields in the documents is of imageUrl type and is a reference (pathname) to an image in Firebase Storage. How can I download paths from Storage?

If you want to download the data associated with the URLs that you already have, then you should perform separate Cloud Storage calls. There is no way you can download them at the same time you perform the batch operations.

Comment: I think they are asking about uploading a text file, not doing a batch write. ??

Comment: @Jay I think the OP is referring to uploading the data that exists in the file, not the file itself. Is that correct, Erol?

Comment: Oops, my comment was unclear. I didn't mean uploading the file. I meant importing the data within the file - similar to the import function in the RTDB Console. I thought that because the OP says they "have the data in a CSV file". Need clarity on that one.

Comment: @Jay Yep, looking forward to seeing Erol's clarifications.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful comments. Data will be in a text file exported from an Excel Workbook (or typed directly). Fieldnames as column headers data in rows. One of the fields  contains String type data which is path to image urls.

Comment: So you want to import those files directly or do you want to read the data that exists in those files first and then write the data to the database?

Comment: My objective is to read the data that exists in those files and write to the database. If I read the files directly I will still need to extract the data inside and write to the database.

Comment: So reading a . CSV file and creating objects out of the data would be an easy job. Right after that, you can use batch writes, as explained in my answer above.

Comment: Can I help you with other information?